# How to get covariance matrix for random effects (BLUPs/conditional modes) from lme4

Tags: r, matrix, covariance, lme4

So, I've fitted a linear mixed model with two random intercepts in R:

```
Y = X beta  + Z b + e_i,
```

where `b ~ MVN (0, Sigma)`; `X` and `Z` are the fixed- and random-effects model matrices respectively, and `beta` and `b` are the fixed-effect parameters and random-effects BLUPs/conditional modes.

I would like to get my hands on the underlying covariance matrix of `b`, which doesn't seem to be a trivial thing in `lme4` package. You can get only the variances by `VarCorr`, not the actual correlation matrix.

According to [one of the package vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) (page 2), you can calculate the covariance of beta: `e_i * lambda * t(lambda)`. And all those components you can extract from the output of `lme4`.

I was wondering if this is the way to go? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify your math notation (is Xbeta actually X * beta ? probably you should also tell what beta, b, sigma are; although I'm not an expert and for *some* those notations can be obvious). Remember that clearer you write you question, more likely and faster you get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Yes, Xbeta was supposed to be X*beta. Beta was fixed effects vector of design matrix X, b was the random effetcs vector and sigma was the variance covariance matrix of b. Thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?ranef`:

> If ‘condVar’ is ‘TRUE’ each of the data frames has an attribute
>   called ‘"postVar"’ which is a three-dimensional array with symmetric
>   faces; each face contains the variance-covariance matrix for a
>   particular level of the grouping factor. (The name of this attribute
>   is a historical artifact, and may be changed to ‘condVar’ at some
>   point in the future.)

Set up an example:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
rr <- ranef(fm1,condVar=TRUE)
```

Get the variance-covariance matrix among the `b` values for the intercept

```
pv <- attr(rr[[1]],"postVar")
str(pv)
##num [1:2, 1:2, 1:18] 145.71 -21.44 -21.44 5.31 145.71 ...
```

So this is a 2x2x18 array; each slice is the variance-covariance matrix among the conditional intercept and slope for a particular subject (by definition, the intercepts and slopes for each subject are independent of the intercepts and slopes for all other subjects).

To convert this to a variance-covariance matrix (see `getMethod("image",sig="dgTMatrix")` ...)

```
library(Matrix)
vc <- bdiag(  ## make a block-diagonal matrix
            lapply(
                ## split 3d array into a list of sub-matrices
                split(pv,slice.index(pv,3)),
                   ## ... put them back into 2x2 matrices
                      matrix,2)) 
image(vc,sub="",xlab="",ylab="",useRaster=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check it out :)

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: Sorry, it may be awhile. But I was trying to understand your word `each slice is the variance-covariance matrix among the conditional intercept and slope for a particular subject`. So what is each slice exactly? Did you mean the covariance of the `b` as the poster asked?

Comment: The reason I asked is because I was trying to use your code to get a estimate of the covariance matrix of `b`, but the result is quite different from the actually covariance of `b` which we used for generating data. Many thanks!

Comment: And what is the difference between getting the covariance matrix using your code above and reading from the `Std.Dev.` in the out put of `lmer`? According to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24452/how-to-interpret-variance-and-correlation-of-random-effects-in-a-mixed-effects-m, they should mean the same thing, but they are not the same value in my experiments.

Comment: I post a question regarding to this question, here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770082/r-covariance-matrix-for-the-random-effect-in-mixed-effects-model Thanks for any help!

Comment: I second @Nan's question